# What are the changes to be included with Constantinople fork?

Tags: hardforks, constantinople

Recently it was [announced](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/a40ltz/constantinople_fork_will_be_occurring_at_block/) that the next hard fork of the Ethereum network mainnet will be at block 7,080,000. From more recent estimates it will occur around [2019-01-15 18:11:20 UTC](http://didtheethereumblockchainreach1tbyet.5chdn.co/).

So what are the new changes that will be after the Constantinople fork?

Comment: Constantinople fork was stopped at last minute and some of the planed features were dropped in the new fork. The referenced question is more precise about the exact features included in the fork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new changes for the Constantinople fork can be found here for every main client https://github.com/ethereum/pm/wiki/Constantinople-Progress-Tracker

To summarize some of the main changes are:

1. Reducing block rewards from 3 ETH to 2 ETH (Lowering inflation).
2. Optimizing code (Refactoring code for the EVM), reducing storage costs for developers
3. Delaying the difficulty bomb by approximately 12 months EIP-1234 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1234 to give time for the implementation of proof-of-stake to be finalized.

EDIT: a great article detailing the changes can be found here. https://icodog.io/tech-analysis/ethereum-constantinople-fork-what-will-change/

Comment: The bit shift, create2 and the new sstore metering look interesting from a programming perspective.