# What changes to make in smart contract to comply with next constantinople hard fork

Tags: solidity, constantinople

Constantinople hard fork in Ethereum is upcoming. So what are the changes we have to make in smart contract to comply with it?

I read this: https://www.coindesk.com/ethereums-constantinople-hard-fork-is-being-delayed-until-2019

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64216/38846

And other articles. But can not figure out, how it will affect current solidity smart contract development.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing you need to change in your smart contract to comply with Constantinople. Newer versions of the solidity compiler will include the bitwise shifting EIP. You don't need to worry about EXTCODEHASH or CREATE2 since you will only benefit from those feature if you need them specifically. The other EIP, net gas metering, will happen passively.